# Optimization of foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, phalcon

I have a collection of elements that I want to group before putting them in a array to send my response back. My loop looks like this :

```
$pages = $section->getPages();
$page_traduction_array = array();
$page_id = null;
foreach ($pages as $page){
    if($page_id != $page->getId() && !is_null($page_id)) {
        $page_dto = PageTraductionsDto::create($page_traduction_array);
        array_push($this->pages, $page_dto);
        $page_traduction_array = array();
    }
    array_push($page_traduction_array, $page);
    $page_id = $page->getId();
}
$page_dto = PageTraductionsDto::create($page_traduction_array);
array_push($this->pages, $page_dto);
```

For a better understanding, each page have a composite primary key formed by an ID and a language ID, so I can retrace every translation for each pages.

I would like to know if there's something I can do to get rid of the two instructions after the loop. Is there a way that can all be done inside the array?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the last two lines, it's a common problem when trying to use that method to group data.

An alternative method would be to re-group the data...

```
<?php 
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

class Page  {
    public $id;
    public $data;
    public function __construct($id, $data)    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

$pages = [new Page(1,1), new Page(1,2), new Page(2,1) ];

$result = [];
foreach ($pages as $page)   {
    $result[$page->getId()][] = $page; 
}

print_r( $result );
```

The core of this code is the foreach, which gives a result of...

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Page Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [data] => 1
                )

            [1] => Page Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [data] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Page Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [data] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

You could then for a `foreach` on $result which will give you a list of all the pages for each ID.